# Trouble retrieving data from higher timeframes in Pine Script (Heikin Ashi)

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I'm currently working on a Pine Script that involves retrieving data from different timeframes using the `request.security` function. The script works fine when I request data from lower timeframes, but I'm encountering issues when trying to retrieve data from higher timeframes.

Here's a simplified version of the relevant part of the script:

```
useHTF = input.bool(false, "Use a higher Timeframe?")
string higherTimeframe = input.timeframe("240", "Higher timeframe")
haTicker = ticker.heikinashi(syminfo.tickerid)
haOpen = useHTF == true ? request.security(haTicker, higherTimeframe, open, gaps = barmerge.gaps_on) : request.security(haTicker, timeframe.period, open, gaps = barmerge.gaps_on)
haHigh = useHTF == true ? request.security(haTicker, higherTimeframe, high, gaps = barmerge.gaps_on) : request.security(haTicker, timeframe.period, high, gaps = barmerge.gaps_on)
haLow = useHTF == true ? request.security(haTicker, higherTimeframe, low, gaps = barmerge.gaps_on) : request.security(haTicker, timeframe.period, low, gaps = barmerge.gaps_on)
haClose =  useHTF == true ? request.security(haTicker, higherTimeframe, close, gaps = barmerge.gaps_on) :request.security(haTicker, timeframe.period, close, gaps = barmerge.gaps_on)
```

The intention is to draw resistance lines based on the high/low of the Heikin Ashi bar after a color change.

However, when I set useHTF to true and provide a higher timeframe, nothing happens. It seems like the script isn't retrieving data from the higher timeframe as expected.

Could anyone please help me understand what might be causing this issue and how I can fix it? Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!